# How can i create a new custom action and trigger it using a button for every row in jtable CRUD

Tags: php, jquery, sql, crud, jquery-jtable

I am preparing a ajax based crud now i chose jtable for this

http://www.jtable.org/

Now what i want to do is create another action like the edit and the delete which is present in every row. So what i basically want is to create another action function that might open a big form or a tabbed panel or something. so i need to get the values of that particular row and then call my php script and then do some task.

Can anyone point me in the right direction...

```
clickablelink: {
    title: 'clickablelink',
    display: function (data) {
        var $link = $('<a href="...">a link</a>');
        $link.click(function(){ /* do something on click */ });
        return $link;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? If so, can we see what you have tried?

Comment: Sir after some googling i found out i could a static column and give some link to do something, i updated my question with it. But instead of going to some another page i wanted to create a tabbed overlay form to add multiple ajax forms....

Comment: Your selector will not work as you have selected the text and markup of the link. Try var $link = $('a') or give the link an id or class that you can select.

Comment: No, that was the basic idea, i can get the id using data.Id and after some more googling i found out that master/child tables might work. I was thinking of tabbed panel earlier as my child table was too big(40 items) but i now am thinking to paginate it and make 4 or 5 such columns